# Is it a solvable Idiom Crossword Puzzle?

Tags: idioms, puzzle

Native Chinese speakers should be able to solve this puzzle. Just want to know if the hints I give are too hard or too easy. And how long it take for you to solve it.

[image]

1. Shock heaven and move earth
2. pitiful; deserving or arousing pity.
3. having common goal
4. be successfully completed once condition is met (when water arrive, a water pathway will form)
5. back against the castle and make a stand
6. wonderful world
7. mutual destruction
8. great number of people spill out to the street
9. calm and corrected
10. chilly night
11. hopeless situation; at the end of one's rope
12. Pine, bamboo and plum

A. No going back (the origin of 覆水難收)

B. party every night

C. united we stand; people's power

D. great distance (many mountains and bodies of water)

E. overnight sensation; awe inspiring

F. match made in heaven

G. red light district

H. tomorrow's yellow flower; old news

I. it is a cruel cold world

J. clear border

K. tough to be at the top

L. be tender to the ladies

M. break rock and shock the heaven

N. total despair

I will post the answer later

Edit:

If you want more hints, you can start from the one below

~

~

~

~

~

[image]

**Edit:**

The Answer in traditional Chinese

[image]

1. Shock heaven and move earth - 驚天動地
2. pitiful; deserving or arousing pity. - 楚楚可憐
3. having common goal -志同道合
4. be successfully completed once condition is met (when water arrive, a water pathway will form) - 水到渠成
5. back against the castle and make a stand - 背城借一
6. wonderful world - 花花世界
7. mutual destruction - 玉石俱焚
8. great number of people spill out to the street - 萬人空巷
9. calm and corrected - 處變不驚
10. chilly night - 夜涼如水
11. hopeless situation; at the end of one's rope - 山窮水盡
12. Pine, bamboo and plum - 嵗寒三友

A. No going back (the origin of 覆水難收)-馬前覆水

B. party every night - 夜夜笙歌

C. united we stand; people's power - 眾志成城

D. great distance (many mountains and bodies of water)- 萬水千山

E. overnight sensation; awe inspiring - 一鳴驚人

F. match made in heaven - 天作之合

G. red light district - 花街柳巷

H. tomorrow's yellow flower; old news - 明日黃花

I. it is a cruel cold world - 世態炎涼

J. clear border - 楚河漢界

K. tough to be at the top - 高處不勝寒

L. be tender to the ladies - 憐香惜玉

M. break rock and shock the heaven - 石破天驚

N. total despair - 萬念俱灰

Comment: The first version is enough for me.ԅ(¯ㅂ¯ԅ), though I filled in 背城一战 before I figured out 一鸣惊人

Comment: Sorry Tang, voting to close for the same reason as this: [Idiom, common phrase crossword puzzle](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/33888/idiom-common-phrase-crossword-puzzle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is what I got without hints:

[image]

and after the hints:

[image]

my personal feelings:

- 万水千山&山穷水尽 is a bit hard without hints, I was thinking about 万里之遥&遥不可及/遥遥无期.
- 背城借一，I didn't even know this word until I googled "带城和一的成语".
- A and 4, I still don't know what they are.

UPDATE after new hints:

[image]

Comment: More hint then: 4. be successfully completed once condition is met (when water arrive, a water pathway will form) A: No going back (the origin of 覆水難收)

Comment: 水到渠成 and 马前泼水？I thought 4 was 大功告成 or 马到功成, and then I cound't figure out what's 马XX大/马XX马. 马前泼水 is a hard word even for native speakers IMO.

Comment: 馬前覆水 https://niulaoye.wordpress.com/2018/01/09/%E9%A6%AC%E5%89%8D%E8%A6%86%E6%B0%B4/ Just fill out the puzzle and I will accept the answer

Comment: Once you figured out 4 is 水到渠成, you would get  '馬XX水' (no going back) for A.  That should narrow it down to 馬前覆水 easily