# Idiom, common phrase crossword puzzle

Tags: idioms, puzzle

I made this for fun, please try to solve it. I will post the answer later if no one can solve the whole puzzle.

Suggestions on improving the hints are welcome. Since I know the answer, it is hard for me to judge if a hint is too detailed or too vague.

[image]

1. Heaven gave me my talents have to be of some use
2. Evenly match
3. The universe will eliminate the ones who don't take care of oneself
4. Complete silence
5. Highly talented or educated
6. From all over the nation/ eight famous mountains in China
7. Copy; Imitate
8. Long historic background
9. Too happy to think of home
10. knowing black from white
11. New wave of talents
12. Incomes can't cover expenses
13. The walking dead
14. kick someone when he's down
15. Take it calmly
16. Sincerity can split  metal and rock
17. Close the stable door after the horse has bolted
18. Not educated and have no skill
19. Deeply shamed
20. Beast like; savage
21. Not essential
22. The People are struggling to survive
23. unrivaled in the world
24. fake laugh

a. Never submit, never yield

b. although committed no crime, your face is loathsome

c. corrupted people are the same everywhere

d. reduce the number but raise the fighting ability of an army

e. The ultimate; no better than this

f. With one touch turns rock into gold

g. Hire on merit base alone

h. Twisting the facts

i. Having good foresight

j. Creating a new world

k. Go straight in

l. Honor bound

m. Desolate place

n. criticizing orally and in writing

o. the sky has only one sun, the people have only one ruler

p. too happy, I can't stand it

q. lose; can't defeat

r. Drown

s. Think carefully and thoroughly before taking action

t. life like; like it is alive

u. make deal with dangerous people; courting disaster

v. great feast

If it is too difficult for you, you can start with the one below that contains hints words

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not actually a question. Though an interesting game, we should not set this as a precedent of what is allowed on this Q&A site.

Answer (score 0):

The answer:

[image]

1. 生我才必有用 (Heaven gave me my talents have to be of some use)
2. 不相上下 (Evenly match)
3. 人不為己天誅地滅 (The universe will eliminate the ones who don't take care of oneself)
4. 鴉雀無聲 (Complete silence)
5. 才高八斗 (Highly talented or educated)
6. 三山五嶽 (From all over the nation/ eight famous mountains in China)
7. 依樣葫蘆 (Copy; Imitate)
8. 源遠流長 (Long historic background)
9. 樂不思蜀 (Too happy to think of home)
10. 黑白分明 (knowing black from white)
11. 後起之秀 (New wave of talents)
12. 入不敷支 (Incomes can't cover expenses)
13. 行屍走肉 (The walking dead)
14. 落井下石 (kick someone when he's down)
15. 處之泰然 (Take it calmly)
16. 精誠所至金石為開 (Sincerity can split metal and rock)
17. 賊過興兵 (Close the stable door after the horse has bolted)
18. 不學無術 (Not educated and have no skill)
19. 無地自容 (Deeply shamed)
20. 如狼似虎 (Beast like; savage)
21. 可有可無 (Not essential)
22. 民不聊生 (The People are struggling to survive)
23. 天下無敵 (unrivaled in the world)
24. 皮笑肉不笑 (fake laugh)

a. 不屈不撓 (Never submit, never yield)

b. 雖無過犯面目可憎 (although committed no crime, your face is loathsome)

c. 天下烏鴉一様黑 (corrupted people are the same everywhere)

d. 精兵簡卒 (reduce the number but raise the fighting ability of an army)

e. 至高無上 (The ultimate; no better than this)

f. 點石成金 (With one touch turns rock into gold)

g. 用人唯才 (Hire on merit base alone)

h. 指鹿為馬 (Twisting the facts)

i. 高瞻遠矚 (Having good foresight)

j. 開天闢地 (Creating a new world)

k. 長軀直入 (Go straight in)

l. 義不容辭 (Honor bound)

m. 不毛之地 (Desolate place)

n. 口誅筆伐 criticizing orally and in writing

o. 天無二日 民無二主 (the sky has only one sun, the people have only one ruler)

p. 樂不可支 (too happy, I can't stand it)

q. 不敵 (lose; can't defeat)

r. 滅頂 (Drown)

s. 三思而後行 (Think carefully and thoroughly before taking action)

t. 栩栩如生 (life like; like it is alive)

u. 與虎謀皮 (make deal with dangerous people; courting disaster)

v. 大魚大肉 (great feast)

Comment: I tried to post my answer image, but failed constantly. So I gave up qwq